# Clear or delete YARN (MR2) application queue

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am using Cloudera Hadoop (`CDH 5.16.2`) for testing purpose. I ran the following map-reduce application two days ago:

```
yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar \
wordcount \
-Dmapreduce.job.reduces=8 \
/user/bigdata/randomtext \
/user/bigdata/wordcount
```

Whenever i start the cluster and check the scheduler, it shows that there are submitted applications. I already tried the following command to kill them and the command output shows that it has killed all applications but later all of them again start showing up.

```
for x in $(yarn application -list -appStates ACCEPTED | awk 'NR > 2 { print $1 }'); do yarn application -kill $x; done
```

Here's the content of `fair-scheduler.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<allocations>
    <queue name="root">
        <schedulingPolicy>drf</schedulingPolicy>
        <queue name="default">
            <schedulingPolicy>drf</schedulingPolicy>
        </queue>
    </queue>
    <queuePlacementPolicy>
        <rule name="specified" create="false"/>
        <rule name="default" create="true"/>
    </queuePlacementPolicy>
</allocations>
```

[image]

Just wanted to understand what's going on and how can i kill them as it's just a test cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I finally figured out that my cluster was actually attacked. It happened because the Azure Network Security Group (NSG) was not configured properly. This also resulted in high-bandwidth charges (*data transfer out*) though I got that waived-off after requesting Azure team. After I restricted both the inbound and outbound traffic, everything got sorted. I killed the applications that were in queue and then they never appeared again.

I was checking online and it seems Hadoop YARN-based remote code execution (RCE) are actually quite common. So kindly make sure your NSG is configured properly.

Ref:

- https://www.extrahop.com/company/blog/2018/detect-demonbot-exploiting-hadoop-yarn-remote-code-execution/
- https://www.cbronline.com/news/record-ddos-attack-aws